# Why didn't the High Blade have Esme kiss his ring?

Tags: scythe

In the book Scythe, Scythe Goddard uses Esme, the High Blade's daughter as blackmail, in order to "control" the High Blade - even making him do useless things like threatening Esme's life if he didn't jump in the pool. Why didn't the High Blade have Esme kiss his ring, granting her immunity from Goddard thereby rendering his plan useless?